# Polling the database for a new rows in database using Stored Procedure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Currently i am executing a stored procedure and sending message to Kafka.

Now I need to execute SP every 2 minutes or 5 minutes for new data  .Is there any out of the box solution for spring boot ?
Can Inbound Channel Adapter help?If yes any example or sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Spring Integration Stored Procedure Inbound Channel Adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#stored-procedure-inbound-channel-adapter).

There are some samples in the `intermediate` folder of the [Spring Integration Samples repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate)

Comment: I edited my question.I am sending message to Kafka and not to database.

Comment: ? Your question is about polling a stored procedure; you would use a kafka outbound channel adapter to send the results of the SP call to Kafka. Spring Integration documentation is currently in the [Spring for Apache Kafka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#spring-integration). It is moving to Spring Integration proper in the next release.

Comment: .I have just one doubt  why  use spring integration.. i.e Message channels.
I can simply call SP(and use timer for repeated calling )  and send the data to Kafka using simple Spring kafka API .

Comment: Of course; it's your choice. Either one is fine. Spring Integration might be more appropriate if you have to perform transformations, aggregations etc, and allows you to separate the concerns.